# probléme with org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J

Tags: java, opencv

i am trying to use OpenCV with java and i am testing Detect FaceDemo but doesn't work, i was searching for answer but i didn't found anything helping 
anyway this is the code

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;


public class DetectFaceDemo {

/**
 * @param args
 */
 public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("\nRunning DetectFaceDemo");
    // Create a face detector from the cascade file in the resources
    // directory.
     Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("C:/Users/Boub/workspace-eclips-juno/TestOpenCV/resources/lena.png");
     System.out.println("imread work just fine");
     CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new  CascadeClassifier(DetectFaceDemo.class.getResource("lbpcascade_frontalface.xml").getPath().substring(1));

    // Detect faces in the image.
    // MatOfRect is a special container class for Rect.
    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

    System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));

    // Draw a bounding box around each face.
    for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
        Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    }

    // Save the visualized detection.
    String filename = "faceDetection.png";
    System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(filename, image);
  }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello, OpenCV");

        // Load the native library.
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        new DetectFaceDemo().run();
    }
}
```

and this is the error

```
Hello, OpenCV
Running DetectFaceDemo
imread work just fine
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_1(Native Method)
at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.<init>(CascadeClassifier.java:59)
at DetectFaceDemo.run(DetectFaceDemo.java:23)
at DetectFaceDemo.main(DetectFaceDemo.java:48)
```

the problem is in:
 CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new  CascadeClassifier(DetectFaceDemo.class.getResource("lbpcascade_frontalface.xml").getPath().substring(1));

i tryed every thing but didn't work out

NB: i am using openCV 3.0.0

Comment: try: `new  CascadeClassifier("C:/Users/Boub/workspace-eclips-juno/TestOpenCV/resources/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");`

Comment: i already tested but i still have the same error
thank you for your anwser

Answer (score -1):

openCV 3.0.0 have bug.
change back to 2.4.10 everything is ok.